# Changing CSS background color for one link while on that page

Tags: jquery, css

Hey all i am trying to only change a background color of a link in my NAV to a different color than all the rest of the nav links only when the user is on that particual page that the link is for.

The code is:

```
$("#nav li ul li a #changeBG1").css("background-color","red");
```

And the nav HTML looks a little like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="custHelp.php">who we are</a>
    <ul>
        <li id="changeBG1"><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
        <li id="changeBG2"><a href="help.php">team</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

However, it does not seem to change just that one, it changes ALL of them. I can not seem to find out how to call the ID of **NAV** and then the ID of **changeBG1** so only that one will change.

The Jquery code is:

```
var url = window.location.href;

url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
$("#theNav").find("a[href='" + url + "']").addClass("theNavsBG");

if (url == 'about.php'){
    $("#nav li ul li a #changeBG1").css("background-color","red");
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: `$('#changeBG1')..`
     should be enough.

Comment: You can do this with just markup and css only if you're interested (and can add a class or id to the body tag of each page.)

Comment: @kinakuta: thats ok. I like doing it via jQuery more :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#changeBG1").css("background-color","red");
```

`id` is the best selector, you don't need to add it "stuff".

You can also add a class to that `li`:

```
$("#changeBG1").addClass('foo');
```

Anyway, it looks likt your selector should be:

```
$("#nav li ul li#changeBG1").css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: I had to add **<a href="about.php" id="changeBG1">** and not the **$("#nav li ul li a #changeBG1").css("background-color","red");** in order to make it work :o)

Comment: Well i meant it did not work when i tried doing **$("#changeBG1").css("background-color","red");**. It only worked when i took the id off the **li** and added the ID to the actual hyper link instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would make a css class and then just add the class to that specific link using jquery to show that it is the current page.

CSS

```
.active {
   background-color: red;
}
```

jQuery

```
var url = window.location.href;
url = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

$("#nav li ul li a").removeClass('active');
$("a[href='" + url + "']").addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, joshmfrankel. Pretty much as saluce did.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/LhbKv/1/

Make life simpler on yourself...

```
.active{
    background-color: red;
}​
```

...

```
$("#nav a[href$='" + url + "']").addClass("active");
```

This code will find the link that ends with the string in the url (courtesy of the `$` in the selector) and add a class to that `a` tag.  If you want to color the `li`, then use the `.parent()`.

```
$("#nav a[href$='" + url + "']").parent().addClass("active");
```

Comment: Thanks for posting that code. I did somewhat similar to what you did there.